# How react-router works when no parent route specified

Tags: reactjs, react-router

All:

I am pretty new to React-Router, when I follow the tutorial here:

https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/#article-header-id-4

The first example is:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route component={MainLayout}>
      <Route component={SearchLayout}>
        <Route path="users" component={UserList} />
      </Route> 
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I hit `"localhost/#/users"`, the UserList shows up(which means it unexpectedly works), what confuses me is:

How does ReactRouter knows **if a route matches** to react UserList component view **even when** there is no path specified explicitly? The parent route(`Mainlayout` level and `SearchLayout` level) of "users" are not specified, how does ReactRouter know where it should go?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdUyEou0LHg

Comment: @Utro Thanks, but could you give a little textual explain, I can not access Youtube

Comment: AFAIK React-Router matches route  through history (hashHistory/browserHistory), It watches on part after 'localhost/#/ '. In your particular case , you define path="users", and you dont have any other parents routes with props "path", therefore you can access 'localhost/#/users', If you define in parent route , for instance "app". Then your path will look like  'localhost/#/app/users', and 'localhost/#/users' will not work

Comment: @Utro Thanks, so it is just like React router use a hashmap to flat the route hierarchy into a list of every possible route ( then I am wondering what is the point of the route without path specified? Are they just for the purpose of group routes )? But I also wonder what happen when there are duplicated paths specified in diff routes which all have no parent route specified?

Comment: path="users" matches "/user". therefore your pathworks. Since user route has parents routes ,thus  they will render too. If you  define 2 same pathes, React-router will take first that matched

Comment: @Utro Thanks, for the duplicated routes part, I am clear now. For the no-path Route part, are those routes used to tell React-Router that there could be potential route and component need to explore under? What if I replace  those no-path Route component with a common component?

Comment: you can ask more questions on [reactiflux](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103538345837068288)

Comment: @Utro Thanks, I will try that, last question, so if I specify a path with slash in front, it will use as absolute path rather then append to parent path structure, is that correct? For example, if I specify a path as "/users"( although this route is under several hierarchy of parent route ) then the URL to hit it is `localhost/#/users`?